# Visual Studio add column dialog misshapen

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-2015

I, since i upgrade my system from windows 7 to windows 10, the dialog for add a datagridview columns is not draw correctly, is unusable!
see this picture:

[image]
i am using visual studio 2013, and vs 2015 with the same problem on both

any clues?

Comment: The picture you posted is inaccessible. Can you re-upload it somewhere?

Comment: ok i fixed the picture

Comment: This doesn't look like something that's your fault. Have you submitted this to Microsoft using the Feedback button in VS? They take feedback seriously and also respond to it via email.

Comment: This definitely looks like an issue with VS itself. I would do as @bytecode77 suggested and use the Feedback button. 

As far as getting it to work, you might try using a different version of Visual Studio.

Comment: ok i submitted as a bug to microsoft, @NathanFiscaletti i have also a clean install of vs2015 and the same happens.

Comment: @Kataku instead of a clean installation, install a different version and migrate the project to it